# Mount sshfs and elevate priviliges (sudo)

Tags: debian, ssh, sudo, rsync, sshfs

I mount a remote directory using `sshfs`:

```bsh
sshfs myuser@myserver:/ /path/to/mountpoint
```

This works just fine.

But I need to acces directories on `myserver` that are only accessible by root.

- `root` login is disabled for security reasons.
- `sudo` is passwordless for `myuser` and this works fine.

So I need to elevate priviliges after logging in with `sshfs`, very much the same like what `--rsync-path="sudo rsync"` is doing when using `rsync`.

**How to do that?**

(fyi: Server is `debian`, client is `Ubuntu`)

Answer (score 4):

It works with adding following option to `sshfs`:

```
-o sftp_server="sudo /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server"
```

path to `sftp-server` might differ depending on the OS.

(via this more than 10 years old [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/159025) on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com))